# Purge single page cache in CloudFlare on post update

Tags: plugins, cache, cloudflare

I'm using Clodflare with the cache all setting on, so all my posts gets fully cached.

Now, when I update a post I'd like to clear the cache of that blog post in particular.

I've installed the Cloudflare plugin for WordPress but they only have an option ([Auto Purge Content On Update](https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/third-party-software/content-management-system-cms/cloudflare-wordpress-plugin-automatic-cache-management/)) that I understand it purges **all cache** on update.

> "Purge Cloudflare cache automatically when you update the appearance of your site."

Is there  more optimal way to clear the cache that doesn't involve purging the whole site's cache?